# How to programmatically check the screen on/off proactively?

Tags: android

I found the following code can do this in a passive way.

```
context.registerReceiver(this.ScreenOffReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
```

But how to get this in a proactive way? That is, at any time, the code can check the current screen is on or off.

Answer (score 10):

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
```

Is it you are looking for?

Comment: Note that as of API 20 (aka Android L) this has been deprecated and the correct way to do this will be `boolean isScreenOn = pm.isInteractive();`